# JS / jQuery: How to filter and serve Ajax called data based on multiple selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make Ajax call to server based on the selection by the user in the following flow:

- User selects a Company
- Ajax call is made to request data of all products based on the Company's selection
- User selects the product by clicking on one of the buttons for example product A, B or C
- User gets the information based on the *selected produc*t of the *selected company*

[image]

Here is my code but the problem is that when user selects Company Alpha and then productA everything goes smooth. But when user selects Company Bravo and then productA I get data for both Company Alpha and Company Bravo for productA by doing `console.log(data)`. Afterwards, if the user selects Company Charlier and then productA, I get data for all three companies for this product.

```
$("#company").change(function () {

    var companySelected = $('#company').find(":selected").val();

    $.ajax({

        url: "{% url 'company_product_data' %}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            company_category: companySelected,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#productA, #productB, #productC").click(function () {
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
                console.log(data)
            });
        },
        error: function (error_data) {
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }

    });

});
```

Can anyone please tell me where I'm doing things wrongly and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please add some markup...

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by markup please?

Comment: Hi, your html :)

Comment: Hi there is no as such HTML involved, just this data is served with a div to user. I think the problem is this line: $("#productA, #productB, #productC").click(function () {
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
                console.log(data)
            });
Do you think ajax keeps the selection somwehere in the queue and when user clicks buttons, it runs the code based on memory?

Comment: I don't think so! First line of your code `$("#company").change` - I'd like to see the html of this element...

Comment: <select id="company">
                {% for company in company_list %}
                    <option value="{{ company.id }}">
                        {{ company.name }}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

Comment: Using Django, I'm basically looping over the list of companies from server and displaying it to the frontend.

Comment: Show the rendered frontend output. The actual source code that is delivered to the visitor of your site...

Comment: and also an example of what `console.log(data)` in the success callback of your ajax returns